# iPad mail shows a copy of sent mail in inbox

Tags: ipad, mobile-mail

My sent emails show in my inbox on my iPad. I have looked but "always bcc myself" is not checked. This problem has started only recently, but I am not aware of anything I may have done to start it. 
It doesn't happen when I send emails from my Mac computer using the same account.

Comment: Are you hitting reply-all and thus CCing yourself? I used to do that all the time accidentally on my iPad, and would constantly get my replies in my inbox.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no I am not doing that.  It also happens when I compose the email, ie not a reply.

Comment: Can you test with any other email providers? Does it happen with those, too?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sending yourelf a bcc: of all mail?

Check your: settings > mail, contacts, calendar > always bcc myself

See if that slider is turned on.

Comment: No it's not that. I did that first. It was a bigpond account and I've given up using it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using imap, you might be storing sent mail on the server. [image: Apple Mail Account Settings -> Mailbox Behavior Tab]

If you uncheck that, you won't see the emails on your other devices, because you won't be keeping a copy on the server. (You will have the copy on your local machine)

Comment: Thank you, but that isn't exactly the problem. I am only using an iPad at the moment, no other computer. When i send emails from my iPad to another person, It immediately goes into my inbox as well as my sent folder.  I did check my settings on my google mail account and I couldn't find the exact link you showed me. But from what I can see, the imap settings are correct.